# Is “snitty” a popular American English term? What is its origin?

Tags: meaning, american-english, word-usage, origin-unknown

I came to know the word, “snitty” for the first time from the remark of Mr. William Barr during his testimony on his way of handling of Mueller Report in the Senate Judiciary Committee.
Washington Post (May 2nd) reports under the headline, ”Pelosi escalates attacks on Trump, compares him to Nixon, as Barr’s defiance angers Democrats”:

> Barr dismissed Mueller’s letter as a bit “*snitty*” and said he believed
>   it had probably been written by a staff member.”

Neither of online Oxford or Cambridge English Dictionary carries the word, “snitty.”
But Longman Dictionary explains its meaning as “annoyed or rude to somebody because you are annoyed, together with an example, “I *get snitty about* bad service in restaurants.”

Google Ngram shows the word came into use around 1970, and that its currency made a rapid rise from zero up to 0.0000001853 level in 2000.

What is the exact meaning of the word, "snitty"? Is it just a slang, or "serviceable" English word as being publicly used by a man of dignity in an official situation? What is the origin of this word?

Comment: I would rank snitty as bottom 10-15% of common spoken words, roughly.  Fun fact: currently snitty is at top 1% of look ups. What do you think caused that? =)

Comment: [Snotty, snooty, haughty](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/158011/snotty-snooty-haughty) – ELL. Not even the maitre d' in [Ferris Bueller](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oh-ybAfF7HY) says *snitty*. My spellchecker doesn't like it either, nor does [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=snitty%2Csnooty%2Csnotty&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csnitty%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csnooty%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csnotty%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: Personally, I think Mr Barr opted for the word as a minced *snotty* or worse. He's friends with Mr Mueller but thinks his reasoning spotty w/r/t outlining an impeachment case despite declining to suggest prosecution himself.

Comment: When I was a kid "snitty" was common.  Haven''t heard in years, though (and I made a point to NOT listen to Barr's comments).

Comment: I have never heard of this word until today and have never heard it spoken during conversation. My anecdotal experience, as an American, is this is not a common word.

Comment: As a native English speaker I've read, heard, and used this word many times. It may not be extremely common, but it's hardly rare or unusual.

Comment: So, in a word, no.

Answer (score 22):

***'Snitty' through the years***

The earliest instance I've been able to find of *snitty* where the word is used in its modern sense (derived from the noun *snit*) is from Philip Fair, [*A Marriage Is Arranged: A Love Story*](https://books.google.com/books?id=USxQAQAAMAAJ&q=%22snitty%22&dq=%22snitty%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjzr8GU5f7hAhUdJjQIHcoHCoQQ6AEIVjAJ) (1932) [combined snippets]:

> They looked up at Gay's step.
>
> "'Lo, Gay, ole thing!" from Nance the younger.
>
> Gay drew her brows together in mock astonishment.
>
> "Nance, darling, where did you get a lingo like that?"
>
> "Just where you got yours! It gets in your hair nowadays!"
>
> "Don't get **snitty**, Gay," from Barbara, "just because you've been over talking to the handsome answer."
>
> Gay flushed.
>
> "Is there anything that happens on this place that you don't know of, Babbie?" she asked.
>
> Barbara laughed.

One striking thing about the examples of *snitty* that turn up in newspaper articles in the Elephind database is that the word seems to be disproportionately applied to girls or women.

From Wally Trabing, "[Mostly About People: (Sigh) Troy (Sigh) Dona(Sigh)hue](https://cdnc.ucr.edu/cgi-bin/cdnc?a=d&d=SCS19641021.1.2&e=-------en--20--1--txt-txIN-%252522snitty%252522-------1)," in the *Santa Cruz [California] Sentinel* (October 21, 1964), quoting a 15-year-old female Troy Donahue fan:

> So, uh, we got to where they were making a scene [in the movie] and we were kinda scared to go up to him so then he was there, and we were just looking at him, and he kinda looked at us; probably thought we were a bunch of **snitty** girls.

From "[Cybill Shepherd: From Memphis to Modeling to Movies](https://cdnc.ucr.edu/cgi-bin/cdnc?a=d&d=SBS19720716.1.111&e=-------en--20--1--txt-txIN-%252522snitty%252522-------1)," in the San Bernardino [California] Sun (July 16, 1972):

> Cybill broke into films accidentally. Peter Bogdanovich, a young director, was strolling through a California supermarket when he spotted Cybill on the cover of Glamour. He decided to cast her in *The Last Picture Show* as Jacy, a spoiled, **snitty**, small town high school heartbreaker.

From "[Walter Scott's Personality Parade](https://cdnc.ucr.edu/cgi-bin/cdnc?a=d&d=SBS19780528.1.87&e=-------en--20--1--txt-txIN-%252522snitty%252522-------1)," in the *San Bernardino [California] Sun* (May 28, 1978):

> **Q.** *Why is Princess Anne disliked so heartily by so many Englishmen?—Georgis Mason, Baltimore Md.*
>
> **A.** Princess Anne, 27, has been accused of arrogance, moroseness, lacking in sense of humor. She is not particularly intelligent or well-educated. She makes cutting remarks. Not too long ago, when a group of demonstrators protested her participation in a Sunday fox hunt, she testily demanded: "Who is paying you to do this?" Many of her contemporaries regard her as "**snitty**," resent the fact that they are taxed in order to provide her with a yearly allowance of approximately $100,000.

From a [*Doonesbury* cartoon](https://cdnc.ucr.edu/cgi-bin/cdnc?a=d&d=SBS19810822.1.24&e=-------en--20--1--txt-txIN-%252522snitty%252522-------1) involving Uncle Duke, Brenner (the sometime caretaker of Duke's lodge in Colorado) and Officer O'Malley of the local police department, in the *San Bernardino [California] Sun* (August 22, 1981):

> *Duke:* Look, I'm telling you it was all just a terrible accident! I thought he was a raccoon, for God's sake!
>
> *O'Malley:* Maybe, but I'm going to have to take you downtown anyway.
>
> *Duke:* Now see what you've done!
>
> *Brenner:* You tried to kill me, man!
>
> *Duke:* Look, O'Malley, let's be reasonable. Don't you have some favorite charity?
>
> *Brenner:* Now he's trying to bribe you!
>
> *O'Malley:* Are you trying to bribe me?
>
> *Duke:* Not if you're going to get **snitty** about it.
>
> *Brenner:* Officer, do your duty!

From Lori Mason, "[James' Europeans Light and Pleasant](https://news.hrvh.org/veridian/cgi-bin/senylrc?a=d&d=vcmisc19811009-01.2.36&txq=%22snitty%22)," in the *[Poughkeepsie, New York] Miscellany News* (October 9, 1981):

> Fine performances are also given by Karen Strain, as Charlotte Wentworth, and Anne Bergman as Lizzie Acton. Strain realistically captures Charlotte's kindness and simplicity as a character, and Bergman is effective as a somewhat **snitty** and jealous Lizzie.

From a [column title](http://spectatorarchive.library.columbia.edu/cgi-bin/columbia?a=d&d=cs19910916-01.2.21.1&txq=%22snitty%22) in the Columbia [University, New York] Daily Spectator (September 16, 1991):

> The Dysfunctional Box Or: **Snitty** 'R' Us
>
> Dramatis Personae...
>
> Catherine "My stomach hurts. I have to study now" Thorpe
>
> Kirsten "I had to wait outside for TEN minutes" Fermaglich
>
> Kristin "I don't have anything personal against BOM..." Kanthak
>
> Liz "I can't tell you who I'm dating. It's a secret" Reza
>
> Evan "Can we just read the damn points now?!?!" Ambinder

(Plus a Jordan, another Kirsten, a Jeremy, and a Joe.)

And from remarks by Council person Margaret Little in "[Alto Council](https://texashistory.unt.edu/ark:/67531/metapth152588/m1/6/zoom/?q=%22snitty%22&resolution=4&lat=5063.245796524511&lon=2209.5184952921513)," in the *[Rusk, Texas] Cherokeean/Herald* (September 17, 2003):

> "Sandra Wallace has dealt with me calmly and professionally and I compliment her for that. I can pay, but you (the city) are unreasonable. Gas employees have been **snitty**. I have encountered unprofessional behavior. I know people who don't have services from the city because of the way they were treated."

---

***Conclusion***

As these examples show, *snitty* isn't merely a straight synonym for being in a bad mood or being argumentative or being snappish, snippy, snooty, or snotty. Rather, it goes beyond these notions to imply a kind of childish or adolescent inability to control one's emotions and behave in an appropriately mature manner. It is thus a rather patronizing and dismissive adjective to use—especially in a professional setting—to characterize someone or (in this case) someone's letter.

Answer (score 20):

from **snit** n.  [etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=snit)

> "state of agitation, fit of temper," 1939, **American English**, of
>   unknown origin. First in Claire Boothe's "Kiss the Boys Good-bye,"
>   which gives it a U.S. **Southern** context.

The [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/242235?redirectedFrom=snitty#eid) registers **snitty** 1978, an adjective as:

> slang (orig. and chiefly U.S.). Ill-tempered, sulky.

The use of the noun and adjective are infrequent in print, more frequent in spoken AmE.

Comment: I'm wondering if the spoken form being 'more frequent' is either A.) regional, or B.) just a hair more frequent than 'infrequent'. I've never heard this word, ever. And if I ever saw it in print I probably would have thought it a regional variation of 'snippy'. :(

Comment: I have heard and used it as:  'you snit!"

Comment: I was referring to 'snitty'. I have read "he was in a snit" but i've never heard "snitty". The etymonline quote says this is a Southern usage, but possible it's deep South because I never heard it in Maryland/Virginia/North Carolina.

Answer (score -1):

For my two-pennies' worth, from the early 1980s to the present day, my sister and I made this word up and its use gained currency with friends and family in Liverpool.  We'd coined 'Snitty' to mean = harmlessly silly or amusingly child-like [as an adult]. Later on, in the middle-to-late 1980s, we were amazed to hear Bob Geldof utter the word on television. (I remember his meaning being closer to being 'pointlessly obtuse' or something similar). I've often wondered if Geldof's and my heritage being partly or mainly Irish might explain the coining of this whimsical word

Comment: Hi Petey, this reads more like a comment than an authoritative answer.  I encourage to you take the [tour] of the site and see the [help] to make edits.